# Apollo Client cache merging previous (from other route) and new results when using browser back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, apollo-client

I am using Apollo Client [fetchMore function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#the-fetchmore-function) and configured the [Apollo Client cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#installation):

The Apollo Client typePolicies configured like:

```
typePolicies: {
    NodesTypeOne: {
     keyFields: [],
     fields: {
      nodes: offsetLimitPagination(),
     },
    },
    NodesTypeTwo: {
     keyFields: [],
     fields: {
      nodes: offsetLimitPagination(),
     },
    },,
  },
```

When I use the browser **Back button** (so it'a navigating back to the overview page, without refreshing the page) and navigate from this overview page to another Node *detail-page*, it's merging the results from the previous route and the current route?

In the [useQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery) hook I am using:

```
notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
```

Somehow, when I hit the **Back button**, I have to reset the cache or something?

How do I have to solve this issue?